# How to get the files of remote directory using a pattern with C# and WinSCP

Tags: c#, ftp, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I'm trying to get an specific files from a remote server with FTP/SFTP connection, the issue that I'm having is, I'm trying to get the count of files in the remote directory with an specific pattern. I'm using a mask but is not working for me, it throwing an exception: 
this is what I have

```
DataFile.sRemoteDirectory = "/user/ftpuser/test/";
receivepattern = "Del*";
filesCount =
    session.ListDirectory(
        session.EscapeFileMask(DataFile.sRemoteDirectory + receivepattern))
    .Files.Where(x => !x.IsDirectory).Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`Session.ListDirectory` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory) does not accept a wildcard, only a path.

---

Since, the WinSCP .NET assembly 5.9, you can use the [`Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles) instead:

```
filesCount =
    session.EnumerateRemoteFiles(
        DataFile.sRemoteDirectory, receivepattern, EnumerationOptions.None).Count();
```

---

In older versions, you have to filter the files returned by the `Session.ListDirectory` yourself:

```
Regex r = new Regex("^Del.*");

filesCount = session.ListDirectory(DataFile.sRemoteDirectory).Files
    .Where(x => !x.IsDirectory)
    .Where(x => r.Match(x.Name))
    .Count()
```

See the official example [Listing files matching wildcard](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_listing_files_matching_wildcard) (in PowerShell though).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it work! hope to someone help this piece of code, I used regular expression, where receivepattern is the pattern used:

```
receivepattern = "^[\\d\\w]*" + receivepattern;
r = new Regex(receivepattern);
filesCount = session.ListDirectory(DataFile.sRemoteDirectory).Files.Where(x => !x.IsDirectory).Where(x => r.IsMatch(x.Name)).Count();
```