# Count files in a remote SFTP folder with WinSCP

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I would like to count all files in a remote folder. I found "offical" WinSCP script that lists every file on the folder. But I would like to count then and save the result to a variable. What's the easiest way?

```
try
{
    // Setup session options
    SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
    {
        Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
        HostName = "example.com",
        UserName = "user",
        Password = "mypassword",
        SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx..."
    };

    using (Session session = new Session())
    {
        // Connect
        session.Open(sessionOptions);

        RemoteDirectoryInfo directory =
            session.ListDirectory("/subdoms/admin/");

        foreach (RemoteFileInfo fileInfo in directory.Files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "{0} with size {1}, permissions {2} and last modification at {3}",
                fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.Length, fileInfo.FilePermissions,
                fileInfo.LastWriteTime);
        }
    }

    return 0;   
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I think this will get you what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680848/how-to-get-the-files-of-remote-directory-using-a-pattern-with-c-sharp-and-winscp. Look at the Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles

Comment: Thank you! Worked!
                  `int filecount =
                        session.EnumerateRemoteFiles("/subdoms/admin", "*.php", EnumerationOptions.None).Count();
                        label3.Text = Convert.ToString(filecount);`

Answer (score 2):

session.EnumerateReportFiles

see [How to get the files of remote directory using a pattern with C# and WinSCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680848/how-to-get-the-files-of-remote-directory-using-a-pattern-with-c-sharp-and-WinSCP)

```
    $files =
        $session.EnumerateRemoteFiles(
            $remotePath, $wildcard, [WinSCP.EnumerationOptions]::None)
    var filecount = $files.Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use EnumerateRemoteFiles and get a count once you have all the file info of the main parent directory.

```
foreach (RemoteFileInfo fileInfo in directory.Files)
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0} with size {1}, permissions {2} and last modification at {3}",
                      fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.Length, fileInfo.FilePermissions, 
                      fileInfo.LastWriteTime);

   Console.WriteLine(fileInfo.FullName);

   string FilePath = fileInfo.FullName;

   if (session.FileExists(FilePath))
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Folder exists");

      var a = session.EnumerateRemoteFiles(FilePath, null, 
              EnumerationOptions.AllDirectories);

      Console.WriteLine(a.Count());

   }

}
```